# Is there a way in SSRS 2008 to format datetime to half hour?

Tags: ssrs-2008

Is there a way to format date time in SSRS 2008 to half hour. I am working on a graph and I am sorting by the hour, but i need half hour is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=DateSerial(Year(<datetime>),Month(<datetime>),Day(<datetime>)).Add(TimeSerial(Hour(<datetime>),Round((Minute(<datetime>)+1)/30,0)*30,0).TimeOfDay)
```

Comment: Corrected. Above tested in SSRS2010 and SSRS2005.